# django-Cannot assign "u'Joan Manel'": "despesa.nomTreballador" must be a "treballador" instance

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have been working on a project in which I have to point out the expenses that the workers of a company have.

For this I have created two models, workers and expenses, in which expenses has a foreign key to workers, in the field: "nomTreballador".

When I try to save it in the db I get the error: "Cannot assign "u'Joan Manel'": "despesa.nomTreballador" must be a "treballador" instance."

My models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

KILOMETRATGE = 'KM'
DINAR = 'DIN'
AUTOPISTA = 'AP'
MANTENIMENTPC = 'PC'

GASTOS = (
    (KILOMETRATGE, 'Kilometres'),
    (DINAR, 'Dinar'),
    (AUTOPISTA, 'Autopista peatge'),
    (MANTENIMENTPC, 'Manteniment de pc')
)

NIF = 'NIF'
NIE = 'NIE'
DNI = 'DNI'

TIPUSDOC = (
    (DNI, 'DNI'),
    (NIF, 'NIF'),
    (NIE, 'NIE')
)

class treballador(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, unique=True)
    cognom = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    tipusDocID = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TIPUSDOC, null=False)
    docId = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=False)
    tlf_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\d{9,9}$',message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 9 digits allowed.")
    tlf = models.CharField(validators=[tlf_regex], blank=True, max_length=9)  # validators should be a list
    correu = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    ciutat = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    dataDAlta = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.nom) or 'u'

   class despesa(models.Model):
        nomTreballador = models.ForeignKey(treballador, to_field='nom')
        tipusDeGast = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=GASTOS)
        quantia = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
        data = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.nomTreballador) or 'u'
```

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from functools import partial
from .models import despesa, treballador

DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class':'datepicker'})

class desModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    data = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y'), label="Data    de la despesa", input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'])
    iquery = treballador.objects.values_list('nom', flat=True).distinct()
    iquery_choices = [('','None')] + [(treballador,treballador) for treballador in iquery]
    nomTreballador = forms.ChoiceField(choices=iquery_choices)
    class Meta:
        model= despesa
        fields= ["nomTreballador","tipusDeGast","quantia","data"]

        def clean_despesa(self):
            despeses = self.cleaned_data.get("tipusDeGast")
            return despeses

        def clean_date(self):
            date = self.cleaned_data.get("data")
            return date

        def clean_quantia(self):
            quantia = self.cleaned_data.get("quantia")
            return quantia

        def clean_nom(self):
            nomTreballador = self.cleaned_data.get("nomTreballador")
            return nomTreballador
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import desModelForm, treballadorForm
from .models import treballador, despesa

def home(request):
    form = desModelForm(request.POST or None)

    context = {
        "gast_form": form
    }


    if form.is_valid():
        desp = form.save(commit=False)
        desp.save()


    return render(request, "imputacioDespeses.html", context)
```

I've tried solutions of similar questions but I have not managed to solve it

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are passing a text string to be used as the `nomTreballador` foreign key, while you should be passing a `treballador` instance.

It looks like you're trying to restrict the available choices to a set of distinct `trebellador`s by using a `forms.ChoiceField`, but a better way to do this with a ModelForm is to change the `queryset` attribute of the `nomTreballador` field. You do this in the form's `init` method:

`self.fields['nomTreballador'].queryset = treballador.objects.all().distinct()`

Also you should check the `clean` methods you've implemented because not all of them map to an existing field.

Comment: That worked fine!!! Thankss, but now i get the instance as the choices. Is there any way that i can show the name of the worker? That way I can know which one i choose.

Comment: @JoanManel The `__unicode__` method on your `treballador` class should already be doing that. Maybe change it to `return self.nom or 'u'`.

Comment: that solved the problem, don't understand why didn't work out with the (). Thank you a lot.