# Select field in form based on queryset in the same model

Tags: python, django, widget, modelform

I want a drop-down populated with the results of a queryset in my form for my coach_id field. I only want the user to be able to select one option, not multiple. I'm trying to use a ModelMultipleChoiceField... unsuccessfully.....

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    coach_id = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.filter(assign_as_coach="Person is a coach"), widget=forms.Select())

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = [ 'id', 'first_name', 'surname', 'email', 'coach_id', 'assign_as_coach', 'position', 'contract_type']
        # exclude = ['initials', 'sam']
        labels = {
            'first_name': _('First Name'),
            'surname': _('Surname'),
            'email': _('Email'),
            'coach_id': _('Select Coach'),
            'assign_as_coach': _('Assign as a coach?'),
            'position': _('Position'),
            'contract_type': _('Contract Type'),
        }

        widgets = {
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name', 'id': 'person-first-name'}
        ),
        'surname': forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Surname', 'id': 'person-surname'}
        ),
        'email': forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Email Address', 'id': 'person-email'}
        ),
        # 'coach_id': forms.Select(
        #   attrs={'placeholder': 'Select Coach', 'id': 'person-coach-id'}
        # ),
        'assign_as_coach': forms.Select(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Assign person as a coach?', 'id': 'person-is-coach'}
        ),
        'position': forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Current position', 'id': 'person-position'}
        ),
        'contract_type': forms.Select(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Select Contract Type', 'id': 'person-contract'}
        ),
```

Here is my model:

```
class Person(models.Model):

    FT = "Full-Time"
    PT = "Part-Time"
    C = "Contract"
    Z = "Zero hours"

    CONTRACT_CHOICES = (
    (FT, "Full-Time"),
    (PT, "Part-Time"),
    (C, "Contract"),
    (Z, "Zero hours"),
    )

    Y = "Yes"
    N = "No"

    IS_COACH_CHOICES = (
    (Y, "Person is a coach"),
    (N, "Person is NOT a coach"),
    )


    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    initials = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(default='', null=True, blank=True)
    coach_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    assign_as_coach = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, choices=IS_COACH_CHOICES, default="Person is NOT a coach", max_length=5)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    contract_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='FT', choices=CONTRACT_CHOICES)
    user_name_check = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.surname + ', ' + self.first_name
```

At the moment I have a coach_id select field rendering on my template, which has nothing in it and is badly formatted.

Comment: If you only want to select one option, why are you using a multiple choice field?

Comment: I read on another question that the easiest way to filter based on a queryset was to use a ModelMultipleChoiceField, so I just blindly jumped in without really thinking about it - I've been using for a few months so bare with me.
What I actually want is a select field, but I can't figure out how to base the choices off a queryset, when the outcomes of the queryset could be different every time someone opens the form

Comment: My answer below is similar to another question I answered earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934040/django-cannot-assign-ujoan-manel-despesa-nomtreballador-must-be-a-trebal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename `coach_id` to `coach` (otherwise you will get conflicting column names) and make it a ForeignKey to the same model: `coach=models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)`. This will cause your coach field to become a dropdown.

You can then limit the choices of the dropdown by settings the `queryset` attribute of the field in your form's `init` method:

`self.fields['coach'].queryset = Person.objects.filter(assign_as_coach__exact='Y')`.

Comment: Yes, except the field should be called just `coach` in this case.

Comment: Great I'll try that now. Why not use a Select widget though in the form?
Also, using self in this is giving me 'NameError: name 'self' is not defined'. It seems to work if I use 'Person' instead.... but I don't understand why self isn't working for me

Comment: @R.Young sorry it should be "self" as a string. Isn't what you're getting now a select widget?

Comment: Ah thank you! Yes I am getting a select widget! I had just never heard of anyone creating a ForeignKey to "self" before to make it display like that so i was wondering about it. I'm just tweaking the init method to make it work at the moment.

Comment: @R.Young don't forget to call the init's `super()` method first.

Comment: Thank you sorted that - the only bit I can't get working is the queryset, written how it is above returns no queries even though there are two records in the database that should match (checked in the admin). When I use a different query i.e. first_name="John" it works just fine and returns all the Johns. Searching assign_to_coach is returning nothing though!

Comment: @R.Young try it with `assign_as_coach__exact='Yes'` since right above the definition you put `Y = 'Yes'`.